# Hierarchical parent-child data, showing top-leaf paths & top-inner paths

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have a table (Original_Table) that shows a hierarchy of projects (Top->Unit->Project->Sub-project->Project-Item etc), where there are three "tree tops" (where PARENT_ID = 000000):

| ID | DESCRIPTION | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | TOP_A | 000000 |
| 234567 | TOP_B | 000000 |
| 345678 | TOP_C | 000000 |
| 246810 | UNIT_AA | 123456 |
| 135791 | UNIT_AB | 123456 |
| 468101 | UNIT_AC | 123456 |
| 357911 | UNIT_BA | 234567 |
| 681012 | UNIT_BB | 234567 |
| 579111 | UNIT_CA | 345678 |
| 810121 | UNIT_CB | 345678 |
| 791113 | UNIT_CC | 345678 |
| 101214 | PROJECT_AAA | 246810 |
| 091113 | PROJECT_AAB | 246810 |
| 121416 | PROJECT_AAC | 246810 |
| 111315 | PROJECT_ABA | 135791 |
| 141618 | PROJECT_ACA | 468101 |
| 151719 | PROJECT_BAA | 357911 |
| 182022 | PROJECT_BAB | 357911 |
| 171921 | PROJECT_BBA | 681012 |
| 202224 | PROJECT_CAA | 579111 |
| 192123 | PROJECT_CBA | 810121 |
| 222426 | PROJECT_CCA | 791113 |

This is on Azure synapse which does not support the use of recursive CTE for this type of hierarchical data.

The result I want (To_Be_Table) would have the same number of rows as the Original_Table, with extra columns (LV_ZERO_NODE,LV_ZERO_TEXT,LV_ONE_NODE,LV_ONE_TEXT,LV_TWO_NODE,LV_TWO_TEXT,LV_THREE_NODE,LV_THREE_TEXT ... for 10 levels):

| ID | DESCRIPTION | PARENT_ID | LV_ZERO_NODE | LV_ZERO_TEXT | LV_ONE_NODE | LV_ONE_TEXT | LV_TWO_NODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | TOP_A | 000000 | 123456 | TOP_A | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 234567 | TOP_B | 000000 | 234567 | TOP_B | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 345678 | TOP_C | 000000 | 345678 | TOP_C | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 246810 | UNIT_AA | 123456 | 123456 | TOP_A | 246810 | UNIT_AA | NULL |
| 135791 | UNIT_AB | 123456 | 123456 | TOP_A | 135791 | UNIT_AB | NULL |
| 468101 | UNIT_AC | 123456 | 123456 | TOP_A | 468101 | UNIT_AC | NULL |
| 357911 | UNIT_BA | 234567 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 681012 | UNIT_BB | 234567 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 579111 | UNIT_CA | 345678 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 810121 | UNIT_CB | 345678 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 791113 | UNIT_CC | 345678 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 101214 | PROJECT_AAA | 246810 | 123456 | TOP_A | 246810 | UNIT_AA | 101214 |
| 091113 | PROJECT_AAB | 246810 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 121416 | PROJECT_AAC | 246810 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 111315 | PROJECT_ABA | 135791 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 141618 | PROJECT_ACA | 468101 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 151719 | PROJECT_BAA | 357911 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 182022 | PROJECT_BAB | 357911 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 171921 | PROJECT_BBA | 681012 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 202224 | PROJECT_CAA | 579111 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 192123 | PROJECT_CBA | 810121 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 222426 | PROJECT_CCA | 791113 |  |  |  |  |  |

In terms of a 'tree', I want to get all the 'full paths' (from top to leaf) (A->AA->AAB for example) but also retain the 'sub paths' (from the top to inner nodes) (A->AA for example).

The current query using LEFT JOIN s only give me all the full paths, since all the nodes join together.

```
WITH get_text AS
(
SELECT 
    ID,
    DESCRIPTION,
    PARENT_ID
FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE
),

get_tree_tops AS
(
SELECT *
FROM get_text
WHERE PARENT_ID = '000000'
),

SELECT
    get_tree_tops.ID AS LV_ZERO_CODE, get_tree_tops.DESCRIPTION AS LV_ZERO_TEXT,
    LVONE.ID AS LV_ONE_CODE, LVONE.DESCRIPTION AS LV_ONE_TEXT,
    LVTWO.ID AS LV_TWO_CODE, LVTWO.DESCRIPTION AS LV_TWO_TEXT,
    LVTHREE.ID AS LV_THREE_CODE, LVTHREE.DESCRIPTION AS LV_THREE_TEXT,
    LVFOUR.ID AS LV_FOUR_CODE, LVFOUR.DESCRIPTION AS LV_FOUR_TEXT,
    LVFIVE.ID AS LV_FIVE_CODE, LVFIVE.DESCRIPTION AS LV_FIVE_TEXT,
    LVSIX.ID AS LV_SIX_CODE, LVSIX.DESCRIPTION AS LV_SIX_TEXT,
    LVSEVEN.ID AS LV_SEVEN_CODE, LVSEVEN.DESCRIPTION AS LV_SEVEN_TEXT,
    LVEIGHT.ID AS LV_EIGHT_CODE, LVEIGHT.DESCRIPTION AS LV_EIGHT_TEXT,
    LVNINE.ID AS LV_NINE_CODE, LVNINE.DESCRIPTION AS LV_NINE_TEXT
FROM get_tree_tops
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVONE ON get_tree_tops.ID=LVONE.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVTWO ON LVONE.ID=LVTWO.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVTHREE ON LVTWO.ID=LVTHREE.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVFOUR ON LVTHREE.ID=LVFOUR.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVFIVE ON LVFOUR.ID=LVFIVE.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVSIX ON LVFIVE.ID=LVSIX.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVSEVEN ON LVSIX.ID=LVSEVEN.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVEIGHT ON LVSEVEN.ID=LVEIGHT.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN get_text AS LVNINE ON LVEIGHT.ID=LVNINE.PARENT_ID
```

Thanks for any advice and input.

Comment: A bunch of `UNION ALL` are needed, one for each level, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Salman A, I built it successfully using UNION ALL. It is slow but for the data size it might just be ok